# How to use onkeyup and on change event in jquery to auto field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange, onkeyup

I want to change input field when I change any value. when I will put any value in rate/kg or quantity total value should be changed automatically.

Comment: Should be changed automatically to? And what have you tried yet?

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 1):

i think this should work

```
 <html>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="val">
    <span id="val2"></span>
<script>
var val = document.getElementById("val");
var val2 = document.getElementById("val2");
val.addEventListener("change",function(){
val2.innerHTML = val.value;
})
</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```